# HealthKit: Calculate heart rate average in a day and length of it

Tags: swift, healthkit

Getting familiar with `HealthKit` and i am trying to find the below by query, but haven't manage to do that yet.

During the same day workout 30 and 60 minutes with moderate heart rate (64%-76%) of max heart rate.

```
func getAverageHeartRate(forDate date: Date) {
    
    let cal = Calendar.current
    
    let startDate = cal.startOfDay(for: date)
    var comps = DateComponents()
    comps.day = 1
    comps.second = -1
    let endDate = cal.date(byAdding: comps, to: startDate)
    
    let heartRateType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!
    let heartRateQuantity = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit(from: "count/min"),
                                       doubleValue: Double(arc4random_uniform(80) + 100))
    let heartSample = HKQuantitySample(type: heartRateType,
                                       quantity: heartRateQuantity, start: startDate, end: endDate!)
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It has a generic routine to get any sample type. You should add error checking;

```
  var hkSampleRecs = [HKSample]()

   func getAverageHeartRate(forDate date : Date, minutes : Int, completion :  @escaping (Double) -> Void)
   {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: minutes, to: startDate)
        getDataSamples(dataType : "HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate", startDate : date, endDate : date, completion :
        {
             foundEntryCount in
             var totalBPM = 0.0
             for sample in self.hkSampleRecs
             {
                  totalBPM += (sample as! HKQuantitySample).quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count().unitDivided(by: HKUnit.second()))
             }
             var averageBPM = (totalBPM / Double(self.hkSampleRecs.count)) * 60.0
             completion(averageBPM)
        }
   }

   func getDataSamples(dataType : HKQuantityTypeIdentifier, startDate : Date, endDate : Date, completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void)
   {

     var searchPredicate : NSPredicate?
    
     searchPredicate   = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: .strictStartDate)
  
     let limit = 1000000
    

    let requestedQuantityType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: dataType)!
    let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: requestedQuantityType, predicate: searchPredicate, limit: limit, sortDescriptors: [])
    {
        (query, result, error) in

        if error != nil
        {
            completion(-1)
        }
        self.hkSampleRecs.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
       
        if result != nil
        {
            for r in result!
            {
                self.hkSampleRecs.append(r)
            }
        }
        completion(self.hkSampleRecs.count)
    }
    
    healthStore.execute(sampleQuery)
}
```

Call like this with 30 or 60 in the minutes field, set aDate to start time and date;

```
 getAverageHeartRate(forDate: aDate, minutes : 30, completion:
 {
    average in
 }
```

Comment: But that is not exactly between 30 and 60 minutes during the day, its not actually checking that

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'between 30 and 60 minutes during the day'? You can set the date range down to the minute.

Comment: During a workout... We have 24 more extra hours for the bounty :)

Comment: okay, edits for minute range.